# Karma: .get() not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, karma-mocha

I am getting the following error when running tests in Karma:

`TypeError: model.get is not a function`

This error does not occur when running the application normally. I am using backbone, and the code in question is below:

```
getCardTypeOptGroup: function() {

    var group = this.cardTypeCollection.map(function(model) {
        return {
            name: model.get('name'), //Errors
            aliases: model.get('aliases'),
            value: model.get('name')
        };
    });

    return searchOptionsTemplate({
        id: 'cardtypes',
        label: 'CARD TYPE',
        options: _(group).compact().value()
    });

}
```

I thought the issue was with jQuery, but I have that file included.

```
files: [
    './vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    './vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    './vendor/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js',
    './tests/*Spec.js',
    './tests/*Test.js'
],
```

Is this a backbone related issue?

Comment: What about `underscore`? `map` function extended from underscore.

Comment: You're missing backbone.js in the list of files.